# Unexpected integer overflow in expression

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, constexpr, bitmask

I am trying to get an `unsigned` that will completely be filled with ones (it will be 32 ones in binary representation. I tried to use this:

```
constexpr unsigned all_ones = (((1 << 31) - 1) << 1) | 1;
```

but when compiled (g++ on Ubuntu) it gives the following error:

```
error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
```

What is causing this error? To me, the expression looks good, as dismantled here:

```
1       = 000...001
  << 31 = 100...000
  - 1   = 011...111
  << 1  = 111...110
  | 1   = 111...111
```

I know that I can get the required value by other means (such as ~0u), but what I'm asking is why doesn't this method work.

Comment: Signed integer overflow is an Undefined Behavior (unlike unsigned integer overflow).

Comment: BTW, you could use `constexpr unsigned int all_ones {-1u};` instead.

Comment: Personally, if I want all the bits set, I prefer `~0u`.

Comment: `constexpr unsigned all_ones = ~0u;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression is using signed integer constants and does overflow into the sign bit (which takes you into undefined behavior). You could avoid the error by specifying an unsigned constant:

```
constexpr unsigned all_ones = (((1U << 31) - 1) << 1) | 1;
```

But the expression is still overly complicated and is better expressed as:

```
constexpr unsigned all_ones = ~0U;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that "overflowing" into the sign bit counts as an overflow.

Comment: @YanB. It's no different than incrementing a signed variable until it overflows the lower 31 bits. The solution in this case is to do everything with unsigned types.

Comment: @YanB. -- overflow means that the result is too large to fit in the type. Shifting values so that the result is larger than the type can represent is an overflow. The underlying mechanism might involve modifying the sign bit, but that's not relevant. The value is simply too large.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use the defines in the header climits, that's what they are for, you are basically asking for the biggest value that you can represent for an unsigned integer.

constexpr unsigned all_ones = UINT_MAX;

See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Comment: Since this is C++ you could also use [`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)